# What are these automatically created tables in my oracle DB?

Tags: oracle

I noticed that my oracle db automatically creates tables with names such as `#T10_sid:201349704_1_FiltFilte`.

Does anyone know how these tables are created / what creates them? They are starting to clog up my table list so I would also like a way to automatically remove them (as long as they are not needed).

Can anyone help me there?

Edit:
I am using Oracle SQL Developer, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I don't think Oracle creates tables like that. Must be your application or one of the tools you use

Comment: You could start to AUDIT ddl, then monitor DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL.